# calling Powershell Script from C# Asp.Net Core - not getting Result on Test Server (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core, blazor

I am currently developing a frontend for Microsoft Endpoint Configuration Manager. In order to interface with ECM i want to call powershell scripts from my Asp.Net Core Blazor app.

```
 string script = "get-Hotfixe";
        PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
            powerShell.AddScript(script);
            var result = powerShell.Invoke();
            if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(powerShell.Streams.Error);
                string err = powerShell.Streams.Error.ReadAll().ToString();
                return err + "Error";
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    sb.Append(item.ToString());
                }
                return sb.ToString() +"Success!";
```

My problem is: it work flawless on my development machine, how ever once run it on my testserver there are no values in "result" and nothing in the errorstream. All i get is the "Succsess" message.
The user is the same, and running the command directly in powershell work without problems. The server is running Windows Server 2019.
Is there a flaw in my Code or are there are any specifics on Windows Server that do not apply for Windows 10 Desktop?

Comment: is `get-hotfixe` a typo?

Comment: it is, probally from a version of the code snipped where i tried to get some output through the errorstream. However the error stream is empty. So neither the correct nor the incorrect versio generate any output, which is my main problem